# CSS working (or not working?) strangely

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

So having some issues with my website, specifically with the CSS. I'm fairly new to web design so these things keep popping up. Generally it's easy to figure it out myself but this really has me stumped.

Essentially what's going on is the last two elements in the unordered list for some reason are moved downward (image below). Can't figure it out at all. The only solution I could find was to add a class and manually move it myself.

Similarly, the problem occur with IE 9.0, but only if I enable javascript (which I need to do for my sub-menu items).

Any insight on what's going on (and fingers crossed there is an easy fix) would be amazing.

[image]

```
<div id="main_menu">
            <div id="main_menu_container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=# id="home_button">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=# id="products_button">Products</a></li>
                    <li class="baq"><a href=# id="baq_button">Book a Quote</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="misplace"><a href=#>About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="misplace"><a href=#>Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!--END OF MAIN MENU -->
```

And the CSS...

```
div#main_menu{
    height:45px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:11;

    background: rgb(246,246,246);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%, rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(225,225,225,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#e1e1e1',GradientType=0 );

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);

}

div#shadow_1{
    position:relative;
    background:url('images/shadow_grad.png') repeat-x;
    height:6px;
    z-index:20;
}

div#main_menu div#main_menu_container{
    width:920px;
    height:45px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    width:150px;
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    z-index:21;

    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color:#747474;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li a{
    display:block; 
    color:#747474;

    transition:all .05s linear;
    -o-transition:all .05s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .05s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all .05s linear;
}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li.baq a{background:#3d9dff; color:white;}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li a:hover{
    /*background:#ffab00;*/
    background:#ffab00; /*#3d9dff*/
    color:white;
}


li.misplace{position:relative; top:-18px;}
```

jQUERY Code (don't actually know jquery, so I've had someone else do it. Which means any advice might go over my head : /):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#products_button").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".products").addClass("active_products");
        $(".products_container").addClass("active_products_container");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".products").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".products").addClass("active_products");
        $(".products_container").addClass("active_products_container");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".products").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".products").removeClass("active_products");
        $(".products_container").removeClass("active_products_container");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home_button, #baq_button, #header").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".products").removeClass("active_products");
        $(".products_container").removeClass("active_products_container");
    });
});
```

Comment: is any jQuery code is associated with menu.?

Comment: this is a javascript problem , can you post the script associated with the menu as well, that would help

Comment: may be due to some css injection from your script. post your script, so that we can check.

Comment: not related to your issue, but there is no need to write four seperate $(document).ready() functions. you can put it all in one block

Comment: you have posted some css, but you're missing the css that is most interesting here: `.active_products_container` and `.active_product`

Comment: Can we see it live somehow?

Comment: @xpy

Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/Medjumurac/EtmSW/

Comment: @user1090635 works just fine without the `.misplace` for all browsers. I suppose the problem should be in the main.js, can we see that?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply everyone. 

@xpy Yeah, it appears to work in the jsfiddle fine. That is, I can remove the "misplace" class, and it's fine. As soon as I use the same HTML, CSS and Javascript in my own index.html file though, it all goes to hell. 

The main.js file is whatever little javascript is available there in the fiddle though.

I have actually narrowed it down to the .head_contact_details section. Going to try working on that and see how far I get :)

Comment: It worked!

The problem had nothing to do with the CSS/Javascript related to the menu, but rather to an element located directly _above_ the items that were being misplaced. Something to do with floating it to the right. Have no idea what was wrong.

  As lazy as it is, I just positioned it absolutely and moved it myself. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/KmrZ3/1/ without `.misplace`

so maybe it's css (or javascript) elsewhere you are not showing here

Comment: Hm. Might be. Looks like I'm going to have to go through the whole thing again.

Answer (score 0):

@user1090635 Remove the class `li.misplace{}`
Then Change the css For Centered Menu like this
Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/bsPrabu/EtmSW/6/embedded/result/

```
 div#main_menu div#main_menu_container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:45px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul
{
     display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* IE*/
    *zoom:1;/* IE*/
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Ok, definitely fixes the issue wherein the last two values are misplaced. However, I can't get the menu to center itself now. As far as I know, the div NEEDS a set width in order to be centered using

`margin:0 auto;`

Comment: @user1090635 i updated my answer for centered menu please check it

Answer (score 0):

Please test the following CSS, I have cleaned-up a little bit and added required styles:
(I changed font size, please set to your favorite size)

```
div#main_menu{
    position:relative;
    z-index:11;

    background: rgb(246,246,246);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%, rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(225,225,225,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#e1e1e1',GradientType=0 );

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);

}

div#main_menu div#main_menu_container{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li{
    display: inline-block;

    list-style:none;

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li a{
    display:block;

    text-align: center;
    color:#747474;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    width: 150px;
    line-height: 4em;


    transition:all .05s linear;
    -o-transition:all .05s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .05s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all .05s linear;
}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li.baq a{background:#3d9dff; color:white;}

#main_menu #main_menu_container ul li a:hover{
    background:#ffab00;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: I tested on firefox and it is just fine.